# HttpClient.GetStringAsync is returning a "Result" object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to retrieve a JSON list from my own API with the GetStringAsync method.
when I get it it returns as a "Result" object instead of just a string ?

Then I am trying to Deserialize the JSON array to a list but recieve an error .

This is how the returned string in the DEBUGGER looks from the HttpCLient.GetStringAsync :

```
"{\"Result\":[{\"id\":92,\"name\":\"Chris Hemsworth\",\"birthDate\":\"1983-8-11\",\"role\":\"Producer\",\"originalList\":null},{\"id\":90,\"name\":\"Jennifer Aniston\",\"birthDate\":\"1969-2-11\",\"role\":\"Producer\",\"originalList\":null},{\"id\":40,\"name\":\"Edward Norton\",\"birthDate\":\"1969-8-18\",\"role\":\"Writer\",\"originalList\":null}],\"Id\":71,\"Exception\":null,\"Status\":5,\"IsCanceled\":false,\"IsCompleted\":true,\"CreationOptions\":0,\"AsyncState\":null,\"IsFaulted\":false}"
```

the Exception im getting when trying to convert the JSON object to string:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BuisnessLogic.Actor]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.Path 'Result', line 1, position 10.'
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code:

```
var celebrities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Actor>>(await client.GetStringAsync($"{serverAddress}/values/{GET_CELEBS_COMMAND}"));
```

the Actor class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BuisnessLogic
{
    public class Actor
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string birthDate { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
        public List<Actor> originalList { get; set; }

        public Actor(string name, string birthDate, string role)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
            this.role = role;
        }

        public Actor()
        {

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Person: " + id + "" + name + " " + birthDate + " " + role;
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

The Controller:

```
  using BuisnessLogic;

using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication12.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        public ILogic _Ilogic;
        public ValuesController(ILogic logic)
        {
            _Ilogic = logic;

        }

        // GET api/values

        public ActionResult GetActors()
        {
            return Json(_Ilogic.GetAllActorsAsync(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
}
```

The data management class :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;


namespace BuisnessLogic
{
    public class Logic : ILogic
    {
        static string filePath;
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Actor> originalList;
        const string BACKUP = @"D:\backup.txt";

        static Logic()
        {
            originalList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Actor>();
            filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempList"];
            File.Copy(filePath, BACKUP, true);
            SaveOriginal();
        }



        public async static Task<List<Actor>> GetCelebritiesInner()
        {
            return originalList.Values.ToList();
        }

        public async Task<List<Actor>> GetAllActorsAsync()
        {
            return await GetCelebritiesInner();
        }




        // Try to read the data from the Json and initialize it. if failed , initialize with whatever it got. return 
        private static List<Actor> ReadActorsFromJson(string json)
        {
            List<Actor> celebListReadFromFile;
            try
            {

                var celebJson = File.ReadAllText(json);
                celebListReadFromFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Actor>>(celebJson);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                celebListReadFromFile = new List<Actor>();
                // Empty list/whatever it got in it
            }
            return celebListReadFromFile;
        }

        public async Task RemoveActorAsync(string name)
        {

            if (originalList.TryRemove(name, out Actor removedActor))
            {
                var jsonToWrite = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await GetCelebritiesInner());

                try
                {

                    File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonToWrite);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Unable to remove due to an error.

                }
            }
        }

        public async Task ResetAsync()
        {

            UpdateFile();
        }

        //Saving the actor, adding the name as key & object as value.
        public static void SaveOriginal()
        {
            foreach (var currCeleb in ReadActorsFromJson(filePath))
            {
                originalList.TryAdd(currCeleb.name, currCeleb);
            }
        }

        public static void UpdateFile()
        {
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, string.Empty);
            var text = File.ReadAllText(BACKUP);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
        }
    }
}
```

The update method that goes to the uri and gets the string :

```
public async void update()
    {
        var b = await client.GetStringAsync($"{serverAddress}/values/{GET_CELEBS_COMMAND}");

        var celebrities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Actor>>(b);
        foreach (Actor actor in celebrities)
        {
            actorBindingSource.Add(actor);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "looks like", where **exactly** did you see the string like that? I ask because of the backslashes, did you see that string using the debugger or did you write it to a file or to the console or whatnot? Please be specific

Comment: It looks like your API is serialising a `Task<T>` instead of just `T`. Missing an `await` somewhere in the API?

Comment: Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen , I got that string from the debugger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198089/discussion-between-roman-sterlin-and-kirk-larkin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON shown in your question is a serialised instance of [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netframework-4.8), which includes properties such as `Result`, `AsyncState` and `IsFaulted`. It's clear that this should be a serialised instance of `T` (`List<Actor>` in your case), which usually means there's a missing `await` somewhere.

This "missing `await`" is in your `ValuesController.GetActors`, which is passing the result of `ILogic.GetAllActorsAsync` into `Json`. This ends up with an instance of `Task<List<Actor>>` being passed in, instead of just `List<Actor>`. In order to resolve that, use `await`, like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetActors()
{
    return Json(await _Ilogic.GetAllActorsAsync(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This also requires making `GetActors` `async`, as I've shown above.

Answer (score -2):

First replace `**Result**` with `Result`.

```cs
var stringResult = await HttpCLient.GetStringAsync().Replace("**Result**", "Result");
```

Second create the classes which has the same properties as the json result.

```cs
public class JsonResult
{
    public List<ResultObject> Result { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsCanceled { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public int CreationOptions { get; set; }
    public string AsyncState { get; set; }
    public bool IsFaulted { get; set; }
}

public class ResultObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string birthDate { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string originalList { get; set; }
}
```

And than deserialize the string with:

```cs
var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(result);
```

And `resultObject` will contain the whole result.

Comment: Sorry, the "*** Result**" It was me trying to make it bold here, its not realy in the code, I do have an object with the same properties as the json result, sorry for not including it, I will edit the original post

Comment: Oh man ... Just Look at my Code. Just wrap the Result class around your Actor class and it will work. Just read my answer and please read the documentations of Newtonsoft.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am getting the same error even after wrapping my Actor class with the JsonResult object.

  var celebrities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(b);

Comment: The weird thing is I don't even want JsonResult to be a part of the Json and I have no idea where it comes from lol, there should be only ResultObject inside the Json, weird.

Comment: After your second edit i finally got your Problem. Kirk Larkin has the right solution.